# WPF: Accessing bound ObservableCollection fails althouth Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is used

Tags: wpf, multithreading, observablecollection, threadpool, dispatcher

I have the following:

```
public ICollectionView Children
{
 get
 {
  // Determining if the object has children may be time-consuming because of network timeouts.
  // Put that in a separate thread and only show the expander (+ sign) if and when children were found
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate 
  {
   if (_objectBase.HasChildren)
   {
    // We cannot add to a bound variable in a non-UI thread. Queue the add operation up in the UI dispatcher.
    // Only add if count is (still!) zero.
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
     if (_children.Count == 0)
     {
      _children.Add(DummyChild);
      HasDummyChild = true;
     }
    }),
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
   }
  });

  return _childrenView; 
 }
}
```

It works great: HasChildren is run in a background thread which uses the dispatcher to insert its result into the variable used for the binding to the UI.

Note: _childrenView is set to this:

```
_childrenView = (ListCollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_children);
```

**Problem:**

If I call the Children property from another ThreadPool thread, I get a NotSupportedException in the line

```
_children.Add(DummyChild);
```

Exception text: "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."

**Why?** I have verified that that code is executed from the Dispatcher thread.

Comment: On which thread was _childrenView set (GetDefaultView is called on this thread)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've run into this problem before ourselves.  The issue is twofold:

1- Make sure that any changes to the SourceCollection are on the main thread (you've done that).

2- Make sure that the creation of the CollectionView was also on the main thread (if it were created on a different thread, say in response to an event handler, this will not usually be the case).  The CollectionView expects modifications to be on "its" thread, AND that "its" thread is the "UI" thread.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that wherever I change _children or _childrenView I must make sure to be on the main thread? In that case it would make very much sense to encapsulate all that "main thread checking logic" into a class of its own. Do you know if anyone has already built such a thing?

Comment: I don't know of one existing as part of an existing framework, but you are correct in that it could probably be coded as a pretty straightforward subclass...  the key is being sure that all the mutators perform the necessary thread-checking.

Comment: Looking for the most elegant way of encapsulating thread-safety checks I found and like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869126/silverlight-observablecollection-raising-collectionchanged-on-ui-thread. I had to replace Invoke with BeginInvoke, though. Currently I am playing around with that.

Comment: Thank you, GWLlosa, you are correct. I finally managed to implement all the required changes and ... it works!